# Как сделать так, чтобы телеграм бот (aiogram) прислал сообщение с картинками и inline-клавиатурой?

Tags: aiogram, aiogram-3.x

У бота есть функция "Заказа атрибутики". Есть MediaGroupBuilder, выводящий сообщение вместе с фотографиями, можно ли как-то добавить к этому сообщению inline-клавиатуру? (сейчас вывод, как на фото) (В документации не нашёл, погуглил, ничего не увидел)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
@router.callback_query(lambda query: query.data == "start_attribute_order")
async def start_attribute_order(query : types.CallbackQuery, state: FSMContext):    
    album_builder = MediaGroupBuilder(
        caption="Доступная атрибутика"
    )
    photos = [
        "https://img-lcwaikiki.mncdn.com/mnresize/1024/-/pim/productimages/20221/5422056/l_20221-s20637z8-csw_a2.jpg",
        "https://legionmurmansk.ru/images/thumbnails/1143/1000/detailed/2/%D0%A7%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%84%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0.jpg",
        "https://files.giftsoffer.ru/reviewer/tb/99/5190.60_15.jpg"
    ]
    for photo in photos:
        album_builder.add_photo(media=photo)
    
    kb = [
        [types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Кепка", callback_data="Кепка"),],
        [types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Футболка черная", callback_data="Футболка черная"),],
        [types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Футболка белая", callback_data="Футболка белая"),],
    ]
    keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(inline_keyboard=kb)

    await query.message.answer_media_group(media=album_builder.build(), reply_markup=keyboard)
    await state.set_state(OrderDialog.order_item)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

К медиагруппе нельзя прикрепить инлайн клавиатуру. Такой параметр отсутствует и в [документации](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendmediagroup) к sendMediaGroup